# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity in Selenium for ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to fetch data from a website  using  Selenium automation  when i am trying to access data from that web site i am getting following exception

```
run:
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 15621
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/ContentType
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$EntityWithEncoding.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:411)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:306)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at pocmandi.PocMandi.main(PocMandi.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 12 more
```

Here is my cod

```
package pocmandi;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.sql.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class PocMandi {

    Statement st = null;
    Connection cn = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        int j = 0;
        String htmlTableText = null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SHAKTI\\Desktop\\JarFiles\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String commodity = "Jo";
        String commo[] = {"Paddy", "Rice", "Jwar", "Barley", "Corn", "Wheat", "Jo", "Bejhar", "Jai", "Urad", "Moong", "Chana", "Matar"};
        for (String com : commo) {
            String sDate = "27/03/2014";
            String url = "http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx";
            driver.get(url);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText(com);
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
            // WebElement find=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"));
            htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
      //  String html=find.getText();
            // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
            htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replace("S.No.DistrictMarketPrice", "");
            htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replaceAll("\\s(\\d+\\s[A-Z])", "\n$1");
            htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replaceAll("(?=(.*?[ ]){4,}).*?[\n\r]", "");
            htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replace("S.No. District Market Price", "");
            System.out.println(htmlTableText);

            String s[] = htmlTableText.split("");
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(htmlTableText);
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) // for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
            // if(str.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String no = str.nextElement().toString();

                String city = str.nextElement().toString();
                String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();
                String price = str.nextElement().toString();
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mandi", "root", "");
                //insert them into the database
                PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("insert into commoditydemo values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, no);
                ps.setString(2, city);
                ps.setString(3, mandi);
                ps.setString(4, price);
                ps.setString(5, com);
                ps.setString(6, "0");
                j = ps.executeUpdate();
                cn.close();

            }
        }
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        if (j == 1) {
            System.out.println("data inserted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not inserted");
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get my output and remove this Exception?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you missing some jars on classpath, check you CP settings

Comment: i added Following jar

Comment: So, it fails only with Chrome Driver?

Comment: it fails with chrome and frifox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your code I tried the following:

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "t:\\Others\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    String url = "http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx";

    driver.get(url);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Paddy");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys("27/03/2014");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.close();
```

}

It works fine with FireFox (29.0) and Chrome (34.0) drivers. I used the following jar-s:

- selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar
- selenium-java-2.41.0.jar
- junit-dep-4.11.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

You should check your project build path and add the appropriate jar-s. But you can find the missing class file in the selenium-server-standalone-2.XY.0.jar if you open it: selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar\org\apache\http\entity\ContentType

Another way is to use httpcore.jar (httpcore-4.3.jar) that contains the missing class file.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually because you are using old version of the selenium java binding, i guess lower than 2.40.0 as this selenium version is missing org/apache/http/entity/ContentType 
(itself internally)

so there are **two** solutions to it.

**Option 1- You wish to keep selenium 2.40.0 or lower**

If you wish of keeping the old selenium 2.40.0 or lower then you have to add missing jar to your project yourself, if you are using maven below is the dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
</dependency> 
                     or
```

[link to download the hhtpcore 4.3 jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3)

**Option 2- You can update the old selenium 2.40.0 or lesser to 2.53.0 or latest 3.4.0**

Please update to a new selenium version like selenium 2.53.0 or latest Selenium 3.4.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[link for the selenium jar 2.53.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.53.0)

```
                    **or** 

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```