# What is causing JBrowserDriver WebDriverException: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to create a working implementation of JBrowserDriver in Windows 10 with JDK 8 and InteliJ 2017, but am encountering an exception that I am unable to resolve. Does anyone know why I might be getting this exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials
```

I've been successful in setting up working implementations of EdgeDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver, and PhantomJSDriver. Unfortunately this exception with JBrowserDriver continues to confound me.

The class looks like this:

```
package app;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Timezone;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Settings;

public class Go {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_DENVER).build());
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The Maven pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>app.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>app.Go</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html -->
                <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.machinepublishers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbrowserdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'NeonFlimsy', ip: '10.0.0.224', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: TestJBrowserDriver
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Util.handleException(Util.java:139)
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver.<init>(JBrowserDriver.java:352)
    at app.TestJBrowserDriver.launch(TestJBrowserDriver.java:16)
    at app.Go.main(Go.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.getRemoteInterfaces(Util.java:244)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.getRemoteInterfaces(Util.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Util.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:224)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:383)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:346)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:225)
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.RemoteObject.<init>(RemoteObject.java:26)
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.AlertServer.<init>(AlertServer.java:46)
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Context.<init>(Context.java:65)
    at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriverServer.setUp(JBrowserDriverServer.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the error stack trace.

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials
```

*WebDriverException* was raised during initialization of *JBrowser*.

---

### Analysis :

- First of all I suspect there is something wrong in :

  ```
  JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_DENVER).build());
  ```
- *JBrowserDriver* being a third party jar should have been configured as :

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_DENVER).build());
  ```
- Next, you see [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104058/selenium-webdriver-java-eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/47111733#47111733) as **org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials** was not resolved runtime.

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/security/Credentials
  ```
- This issue is pretty much similar to the QA [How can I resolve my class from a different jar with same structure like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192621/how-can-i-resolve-my-class-from-a-different-jar-with-same-structure-like-another)

---

### Reasons :

There can be multiple possibilities behind the reason you are seeing [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730321/selenium-testng-maven-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-sele/50739624#50739624) as follows :

- The preliminary reason seems to be that the *class was not found in the classpath*. As you have mentioned that you are adding:

  ```
  import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
  ```

  related jar as an external dependency. Make sure you have the correct **version** of the jar where the scope is properly defined and it is bundled when you package your application.

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.machinepublishers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbrowserdriver</artifactId>
      <version>0.17.11</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion on [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104) in the discussion [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)
- Finally, with the purview of [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) the [pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366341/how-to-automatically-update-selenium-version-in-pom/48367312#48367312) contains multiple references as follows :

  - First:

    ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - Second:

    ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - Third:

    ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - Forth:

    ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ```

---

### Solution :

The possible solutions would be :

- Ensure you have the correct **version** of the *jar* where the *scope* is properly defined and it is bundled when you package your application.
- Remove the additional (unused) dependencies as per [Selenium Maven Information](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp).

Comment: Wow thank you DebanjanB for your detailed analysis and very helpful explanations. Following your guidance my implementation runs correctly now. Among the many things you pointed out, the <artifactId>jbrowserdriver</artifactId> <version>0.17.11</version> was the underlying cause of the NoClassDefFoundError exception. I am now using <version>1.0.0-RC1</version>