# why different projects require different referenced libraries when using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need to know if I have configured all required JARs & library files within my Selenium WebDriver installation, why I need to install referenced libraries again whenever I create a new project with WebDriver.

Thanks & Regards,
Manisha

Comment: Use maven... and let it handle all dependencies. https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

Comment: Thanks, however still would like to know why all library files need to be configured again & again for different projects, when using Selenium WebDriver

Comment: To achieve different functionalities we need to add those libraries. Selenium just give support to automate browser, to read excel or take screenshots, generate reports we need these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a *New Project* it's a :

- **New Client** for whom you are developing the *Test Scripts*.
- **New Requirements** and acording to  the specification you are developing the *Test Scripts*.
- A client can have a requirement of *Selenium v2.53* where as another client can opt for the latest release of *Selenium* i.e *Selenium v3.11.0*
- A client can have a requirement of based on released [Selenium Jars](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) where as another client can have a requirement of dynamic *Selenium Jars* based on [*Maven Repository*](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) or *Gradle*. You can find a discussion on how to [How to automatically update selenium version in POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366341/how-to-automatically-update-selenium-version-in-pom/48367312#48367312)
- A client can have a requirement of using *TestNG* framework where as another client can opt to use _JUnit_framework.
- A client can have a requirement of using *Cucumber* with JDK where as another client can opt to have  *Cucumber* with JDK .

So following the above mentioned factors each of your *Client* and their respective *Requirements* your *Project Structure* and *Binary Specifications* may vary from *project* to *project*. The *IDE* you use e.g. **Eclipse** provides you the flexibility to add the *External Jars* through **Java Build Path** through *Project Settings* and through **pom.xml** recognized by *Maven*.

For all the reasons mentioned above you need to configure all required *JARs* & *library files* in your new *Project*.

Comment: Thanks, so am using Selenium Oxygen using ecplise IDE..for each project I create in that , installing referenced libraries again & again for each new project isn't quiet feasible