# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [null] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions using SeleniumGrid in Docker

Tags: maven, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running selenium grid and has 2 nodes connected to it. But when I try to run a test script (.java) it gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-23" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [null] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 3e5f8fb2ae3b0c5cddc8817f80eb8fe1]
Command duration or timeout: 92 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

In the VNC client the chrome browser opens up but the url is not getting loaded and the error is thrown.

Note: The script is run from another docker container using maven.

When I run the script as a java application, it works fine, but in docker, I'm getting the error.**

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-23" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [null] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 3e5f8fb2ae3b0c5cddc8817f80eb8fe1]
Command duration or timeout: 92 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

...implies that the *Selenium Grid Node* was unable to communicate with the *Selenium Grid Hub*.

---

### Deep Dive

This error is defined in [ActiveTestSessions.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/selenium/+/8befac087e24735b91ed551953562fac1b64f13d/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/ActiveTestSessions.java#96) and is defined as:

```
public TestSession getExistingSession(ExternalSessionKey externalkey) {
    TestSession sessionByExternalKey = findSessionByExternalKey(externalkey);
    if (sessionByExternalKey == null) {
      SessionTerminationReason sessionTerminationReason = reasons.get(externalkey);
      String keyId = externalkey != null ? externalkey.getKey() : "(null externalkey)";
      if (sessionTerminationReason != null) {
          String msg = "Session [" + keyId + "] was terminated due to " + sessionTerminationReason;
          log.fine(msg);
          throw new GridException(msg);
      } else {
          String msg = "Session [" + keyId + "] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\n"
          + "Active sessions are" + this.unmodifiableSet();
          log.fine(msg);
          throw new GridException(msg);
      }
    }
    return sessionByExternalKey;
}
```

As per the following discussions:

- [Session [....] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/695)
- [Selenium 3.9.0 & above gives error "Session [null] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions." on geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6336)

It seems this error stems out when:

- *Selenium Grid Hub*, *Selenium Grid Node* and the *Client Process* are initiated/spawned from **different versions** of *Selenium* client.

---

### Solution

Ensure that *Selenium Grid Hub*, *Selenium Grid Node* and the *Client Process* all of them uses the same version of *Selenium* client i.e. **Selenium v3.141.59**

---

### Update 1

In normal circumstances you should have observed [Selenium Webdriver + Java - Eclipse: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104058/selenium-webdriver-java-eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/47111733#47111733) incase of presence of multiple  versions of the same jar. A bit more details interms of your *Test Architecture* would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. Possibly you need to *clean up* as follows:

- `mvn clean`
- `mvn install`
- or `mvn clean install`
- `mvn test`

---

### Update 2

As the last resort you can delete the `MAVEN_HOME` i.e. `~/.m2` and re-initiate the build process.

Comment: But then how is the script running when I am running it as an independent java application. I'm not sure about this. I had already set both the gird and node version to 3.141.59-zinc.

Comment: @MidhunKG Checkout the updated answer and let me know if any question.

Comment: I thought it was the version problem and updated my pom.xml selenium dependency to 3.141.59 but still the same error. I tried running with maven clean install

Comment: @MidhunKG Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Still Not working. In my pom file where I specify the version for selenium a warning is shown "Overriding managed version 2.53.1 for selenium-java". Does this have anything to do with it not working.