# Firefox 56.0 is not opening up using Selenium 3.7 with Gecko driver 0.19

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open Firefox 56 with [Selenium 3.7](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) release dated 2017-11-02 and path in my Win 8.1 is set up in environment variables too.I get NoClassDefFoundError

Error screenshot: https://snag.gy/mI23xp.jpg

Versions information:
Java 1.8.091 |
Selenium 3.7 | Gecko driver geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip | Firefox 56

My code:

```
 package new_Package;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Selenium_Basics {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Gecko Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

I have tried workarounds from similar questions suggested on StackOverFlow and other sites like trying with different Firefox version and setting DesiredCapabilities or setting up binary for the Firefox but nothing has still worked out.

Alternatively I tried this recently to debug at checkpoints.

```
package new_Package;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Selenium_Basics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Gecko Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Debug 1");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Debug 2");
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

The error stack trace:

Debug 1

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:12121 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:12:07.291Z'
System info: host: 'LENOVO', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
    at new_Package.Selenium_Basics.main(Selenium_Basics.java:12)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:12121 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity in Selenium for ChromeDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471340/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-httpentity-in-selenium-for-chromedriver)

Comment: @JeffC : I tried it out but that is not helping out.I even tried downgrading the Firefox version to 45.

Comment: You stated, `I have not configured Selenium standalone server jar`. That is the problem. You need to add that jar.

Comment: @JeffC I did that too now but it isn't working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting another error or ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such error in your code block. The error **`NoClassDefFoundError`** is observed when the **`JRE`** can't find a **`Class`**.

In simple words the required `imports` or `jar` files are not available. In this case you need to follow the following steps:

1. Remove all the jars referring to previous versions of **`Selenium standalone server`** & **`Selenium Java client`**
2. Import only the **`selenium-server-standalone-3.7.0`**.
3. In your **`IDE`** within **`Project`** menu, select the option **`Build Automatically`** and execute the **`Clean`** option for all of your Projects.
4. Execute your Test.